# Rails 5: JS files not loading in Production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, x-editable

I'm using Rails 5 and Ruby 2.5, and deploying to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

All the stylesheets and CSS files are loading correctly in Production, however the Javascript files are not loading properly in Production. Everything works perfectly in Development.

I'm thinking that the issue is that in Production, I only see one .js file which has crammed a lot of javascript files together which is making it not load correctly.

This is how it looks on localhost:
[image: JS files on localhost]

And this is how it looks on the production server:
[image: JS files on production server]

When I do a search through the production .js file I am missing a lot of code that is in those separate JS files loaded on localhost.

I have tried running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile` and I can see all my assets in the /public/assets folder.

My production.rb file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
    config.cache_classes = true
    config.eager_load = true
    config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
    config.read_encrypted_secrets = true
    config.public_file_server.enabled = true
    config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
    config.assets.compile = false
    config.log_level = :debug
    config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]
    config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
    config.i18n.fallbacks = true
    config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
    config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

    if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
        logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
        logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
        config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
    end

    config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
    config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
    config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

    config.assets.digest = true
    Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js ^[^_]*.css *.css.erb )

end
```

My application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require editable/bootstrap-editable
//= require editable/bootstrap2-editable
//= require editable/rails
//= require_tree .
```

The `editable` gem is [x-editable](https://github.com/werein/x-editable-rails) and is used for In Place Editing.

**UPDATE**

This is how the stylesheets and javascripts are loaded in the application.html.erb file:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Comment: try running app in production env on your local. It will help you more. I think merging of multiple files is write as js compressor compressed it. Did you get any js error on web console?

Comment: No, the weird thing is that I'm not getting any js errors on the web console, both in dev and prod.

Comment: config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/editable/rails"

Comment: @rohankharvi I tried adding this to application.rb but nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried running rake with no env specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by just manually downloading each JS file that appeared in the source code in Development, then uploading them to the server, and importing them manually one by one in the code as in the locahost screenshot!

Answer (score 2):

Try to `config.assets.compile` `false` to `true` then it will be like below

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Hope it will work